# Flux query to get the average per 15 minutes for the last 30 day

Tags: time-series, influxdb, flux, influxdb-2

I have an InfluxDB bucket called *my_data*.
It has the energy consumption (EDC) values as field.
The measurement is called my_portal.
The tag is serialNumber.
The data is stored every 15 minutes via [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT).

I want to write a flux query to get the average consumption values for the last 30 days of each day in the week.

For example: I want the average consumption of the last 4 Sundays and Mondays and Thursdays and Wednesdays   and so.
And the average should be per 15 minutes.

So I will get seven records for each day in the week and each record should have the average per 15 minutes.
How can I write that query?

I tried to use

```
|> aggregateWindow(every: 15, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
```

But like that I will get the per 15 minutes only and not per day per 15 minutes.

So I want to get these results.
The last four Mondays is the mean at 10:00 = 3 and at 10:15 2 and at 10:30 1.5 and so on.

I want to get the average consumption per 15 minutes for each day of the week.

So in total, I will have seven days. Each has an average for the last four same days (for example, the last four Sundays or last four Wednesdays) per 15 minutes.

For example: the energyConsumption is 3 at 10:00 and at 10:15 is 2.5 and at 20:00 is 5 at Monday 3 April.

And The energyConsumption is 2 at 10:00 and at 10:15 is 1 and at 20:00 is 4 at Monday 10 April.

And The energyConsumption is 4 at 10:00 and at 10:15 is 2 and at 20:00 is 2 at Monday 17 April.

And The energyConsumption is 1 at 10:00 and at 10:15 is 3 and at 20:00 is 6 at Monday 24 April

So I want to get the average per 15 minutes for these last Mondays for example.

The average will be at 10:00 2.4 and at 10:15 = 2.125 and at 20:00 = 4.25 and so on for every 15 minutes.

So I want to group, for example, the last 4 Sundays and get the average per 15 minutes of them.